# Making a Facebook Android SDK APKLIB

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-maven-plugin

So I've seen several partial answers to this problem but no complete solution (or the solutions are over 6+ months old). Hopefully someone can explain the solution to this problem in full.

I'm currently using the instuctions here https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib to make the package, but I still don't understand them even though I've also looked at the examples.

The process, as far as I can tell, involves making a pom.xml for the Facebook SDK then a parent pom.xml to build it? I'm really not sure and would appreciated a step by step process explaining this (assume I have 0 clue on what to do besides install android maven and the checking out the facebook android sdk locally).

Comment: I have started creating a maven fork although mvn test fails so I am asking another question to fix that. Look here: https://github.com/Bizzby/facebook-android-sdk any insights would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Someone's already done it: https://github.com/avianey/facebook-api-android-maven

See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14707612/473201

Comment: That's an AAR (i.e. a binary distribution of an Android Library project), not an APKLIB (i.e. a source code distribution of an Android Library project).