# Could not find tool aapt. Please provide proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I am trying to build a android project using maven. But when I run :
    mvn clean install 
I get the following error:

Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.4.1:generate-
sources failed: Could not find tool 'aapt'. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <\sdk><\path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin . As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME. -> [Help 1]

I have set my ANDROID_HOME to the sdk directory. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 39):

In the last release of android sdk directory structure has changed. Build tools like aapt or dex has been moved from platform-tools to build-tools directory. Support for new directory structure was added in maven-android-plugin version 3.6.0 but you use version 3.4.1. Changing plugin version to 3.6.0 in pom.xml must help. Here is snippet from my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>src/main/other/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <resourceDirectory>src/main/resources</resourceDirectory>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>17</platform>
                    <path>/opt/android-sdk/</path>
                </sdk>
                <manifest>
                    <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                </manifest>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: For me mentioning the platform version isn't necessary (but upgrading to 3.6.0 is).

Comment: you nailed it! upgrading to 3.6.0 helped

Comment: Just adding the version as `3.6.0` in my pom.xml file has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using android version 17, you might want to try this documented workaround (i.e. I did not find it myself).

```
cd <android-sdk>/platform-tools
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aapt aapt
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/lib lib
```

Comment: I found the solution. Its not the perfect one but it worked. I just copied all the files in the build-tools folder and copied in into the tools folder in the Android SDK directory. (Do not replace the existing files)

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is documented in the [changelog](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog) for version 3.6.0

Just add the sdk platform configuration to the Android Maven Plugin like so

```
<configuration>
  <sdk> 
    <platform>17</platform>
   </sdk>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your pom.xml file,specify the path to your android sdk

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    <platform>16</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The environment variable ANDROID_HOME is used anyway, so mentioning the path here is redundant...

Answer (score 0):

If android sdk version above 21, just add %ANDROID_HOME%/build-tools to to environment variable PATH of your system.

to "Nemin Shah" -- copy files is not such good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I get stuck with the same problem. Finally i managed to resolve the issue after two hours. To make it simple and resolve the issue in 5 minutes i listed the steps below

**Step 1** - In Eclipse update your **Android Maven Plugin** to 0.4.3.2013 using the beta release link
`http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/updates/master/`

**Step 2**

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <sdk>
                <platform>17</platform>
            </sdk> 
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

It will solve the following issues

`"No Android Platform Version/API Level has been configured"`

`Could not find tool 'aapt'`

Hope it helps